# No provider for imaps error in Java stored procedure

Tags: java, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to get emails from my gmail using Java Class saved in Oracle Database. Currently I use Oracle Database 12.2.

This is my Java source code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;


public class GmailInbox {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    throws SQLException, MessagingException, IOException 
    {
        read();
    }

    public static String read() 
    throws SQLException, MessagingException, IOException 
    { 
      Properties props = new Properties();
      Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
      Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
      store.connect("smtp.gmail.com", "*********@gmail.com","password");
      Folder inbox = store.getFolder("inbox");
      inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

      int messageCount = inbox.getMessageCount();
      System.out.println("Total Messages:- " + messageCount);

      Message[] messages = inbox.getMessages();

      System.out.println("------------------------------");

      for (int i = messages.length - 1; i >= messages.length-3 ; i--) {
          Message message = messages[i];
          System.out.println("---------------------------------");  
          System.out.println("Email Number " + (i + 1));  
          System.out.println("Subject: " + message.getSubject()); 
          System.out.println("Date: " + message.getReceivedDate()); 
          System.out.println("From: " + InternetAddress.toString(message.getFrom())); 
      }
      inbox.close(true);
      store.close();

      return("Done");
 }

}
```

It perfectly works in the Eclipse IDE.

I loaded this Java Source into database by

```
loadjava -user <user>/<password> -verbose -resolve <path_to_java_code>
```

Both Class and Source are "VALID" by

```
select DBMS_JAVA.LONGNAME(OBJECT_NAME) as object_name,
       object_type,
       status,
from user_objects
where object_type like 'JAVA%';
```

After that I've created a function:

```
create or replace function TestGmail
return varchar2
is language java name
'GmailInbox.read() return String';
```

Finally, when I'm trying to execute this class in Oracle by this code:

```
declare 
output varchar2(50);
begin 
  output := TestGmail;
  dbms_output.put_line(output);
end;
```

I'm getting the error:

> ORA-29532: Java call terminated by uncaught Java exception:
>   javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException: No provider for imaps

Is there any way to avoid this error?

Comment: The protocol is called `imap`, not `imaps`.

Comment: @Poohl Maybe I'm wrong, but I thought that IMAP over SSL is IMAPS. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the case, i've never heard of `IMAPS` before and seems java. I can't find any documentation stating it's supported.

Comment: It is just "missing dependency" problem. In order to run this code you have to have [javax.mail.jar](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/#Download_JavaMail_Release) on the classpath. Oracle database uses it's own java, you must load this JAR file into the database to be available there.

Comment: @krokodilko Thanks, Can you provide me any links or describe in more details how can I do this?

Comment: See [loadjava](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/jjdev/loadjava-tool.html#GUID-B80B4492-55BB-4B75-919C-6E5962380710) for uploading `jar` files. See here an example of loading the [Groovy all jar](http://www.db-nemec.com/groovy/Running_Groovy_Scripts_in_the_Database.html)

Comment: @MarmiteBomber Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`loadjava` utility](https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/JJDEV/loadjava-tool.htm#JJDEV10060) to store the necessary dependencies (which appears to be `javax.mail.jar`) in the database so that Oracle can find them on its classpath.

For example:

```
loadjava -user <user>/<password> -resolve javax.mail.jar
```

Comment: Thx, it works, but one should reload the initial Java Source.